# Unable to get Flowplayer Play button

Tags: html, flowplayer

I am using version flowplayer 5.2.1 (html5) and have tried endlessly to get the play button to function with my existing code , an example could be seen at http://bit.ly/XS2goD

As the flowplayer support is paid, even after buying the license, I donot have any other place else to ask this question

Comment: In flow player there is only center play and pause, do you want another play button on left of progress bar?

Comment: Yes thats what I was seeking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only flow player v5.3 provides you play button customization on control bar. Check the below link

http://flowplayer.org/docs/skinning.html

Comment: So we have to buy flowplayer v 5.3 for this?

Comment: First do a poc on free version for play button. After successful poc, discuss with flow players guy for version upgrade.